# Two consecutive increase in values starts a series of True values until we run into two consecutive False values which starts False values

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataframe

```
       Date                           Ratio
0   1993-01-29                       0.44  
1   1993-02-01                       0.44
2   1993-02-02                       0.45  
3   1993-02-03                       0.44  
4   1993-02-04                       0.44  
5   1993-02-05                       0.56  
6   1993-02-08                       0.59  
7   1993-02-09                       0.58  
8   1993-02-10                       0.57  
9   1993-02-11                       0.54  
10  1993-02-12                       0.53  
11  1993-02-16                       0.47  
12  1993-02-17                       0.42  
13  1993-02-18                       0.38
14  1993-02-23                       0.35  
15  1993-02-24                       0.39  
16  1993-02-25                       0.43  
17  1993-02-26                       0.46
```

I am trying to create a new column 'signal',
which has default value of True

The column 'signal' is looking at column "ratio  " and
looking for when there are two consecutive decreases in value.
When it finds that  all the values FOLLOWING the two consecutive decreases will be set to false, UNTIL
we get two consecutive increases, which will stop the series of Falses.

We then look for two conseutive decreases further down the column, and again set the values to false
till we run into two consecutive increases which will stop the signal

Rinse and repeat for the entire column

So for above column:

The 9th row starts the start of False values because

6th row to 7th row a decrese (.59 to .58) and 7th to 8th (.58 to .57)

This is the start of the signal until
we run into row 17th, which closes the signal because we had two
consecutive increases.

Output should be this:

```
    Signal                           
0   True                         
1   True                       
2   True                         
3   True                
4   True                      
5   True                 
6   True                 
7   True                     
8   True                       
9   False                       
10  False                        
11  False                       
12  False                       
13  False                     
14  False                      
15  False                       
16  False                       
17  True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
(df['Ratio'].diff()
.lt(0)
.rolling(2,1).sum()
.map({2:False,0:True})
.shift()
.ffill()
.fillna(True))
```

or

```
m = df['Ratio'].diff().lt(0).rolling(3,min_periods=1).sum()
s = m.eq(0)
e = m.eq(3)

s.where(s|e).ffill()
```

or

```
(df['Ratio'].diff().rolling(n+1,0).agg(
    lambda x: 1 if x.iloc[:-1].ge(0).all() 
    else 0 if x.iloc[:-1].lt(0).all() 
    else np.NaN).ffill().astype(bool)
    )
```

or

```
s = df['Ratio'].diff().rolling(2,1).agg(lambda x: x.lt(0).all()).shift().fillna(0).astype(bool)
df['Signal'] = ~(s.where(s).ffill(limit = 1).fillna(False))
```

Output:

```
    Date    Ratio   Signal
0   1993-01-29  0.44    True
1   1993-02-01  0.44    True
2   1993-02-02  0.45    True
3   1993-02-03  0.44    True
4   1993-02-04  0.44    True
5   1993-02-05  0.56    True
6   1993-02-08  0.59    True
7   1993-02-09  0.58    True
8   1993-02-10  0.57    True
9   1993-02-11  0.54    False
10  1993-02-12  0.53    False
11  1993-02-16  0.47    False
12  1993-02-17  0.42    False
13  1993-02-18  0.38    False
14  1993-02-23  0.35    False
15  1993-02-24  0.39    False
16  1993-02-25  0.43    False
17  1993-02-26  0.46    True
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop does it:

```py
signal = []
ratio = df["Ratio"].to_numpy()

for i in range(len(ratio)):
    if i < 3:
        s = True
    elif ratio[i-3] > ratio[i-2] > ratio[i-1]:
        s = False
    elif ratio[i-3] < ratio[i-2] < ratio[i-1]:
        s = True

    signal.append(s)

df["Signal"] = signal
```